# Recoding from C to Python

Tags: python, c

I'm pretty much a layman in C and I'm learning Python. I need to write the routine described below (in C) for Python:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{
    float   hold[26], hnew[26];
    float   dt, dx;
    float   t, s;
    float   ho;
    float   time;
    float   f1, d2h;

    int i;
    int nx, nlx;
    int n, nend;
    int kount, kprint;


    dt  = 5.0;
    dx  = 10.0;
    t   = 0.02;
    s   = 0.002;
    nx  = 11;
    nlx = nx-1;


    ho = 16.0;
    for( i = 1;  i <= nx;  i++ )
    {
        hold[i] = ho;
        hnew[i] = ho;
    }

    hold[nx] = 11.0;

    printf("\t\t\t\thead\t\t\t\t      time\n\n");
    kount  = 1;
    kprint = 2;

    time = dt;
    nend = 100;


    for( n = 1;  n <= nend;  n++ )
    {
            /* update solution */

        for( i = 2;  i <= nlx;  i++ )
        {
            f1 = dt*t/s;
            d2h = ( hold[i+1] - 2.0*hold[i] + hold[i-1])/(dx*dx);
            hnew[i] = hold[i] + (f1*d2h);
        }

        for( i = 1;  i <= nlx;  i++ )
        {
            hold[i] = hnew[i];
        }


        if( kount == kprint )
        {
            for( i = 1;  i <= nx;  i++ )
            {
                printf(" %.2f",hold[i]);
            }
            printf("   %6.2f\n",time);
            kount = 0;
        }

        time  = time + dt;
        kount = kount + 1;
    }
}
```

This is my attempt at Python:

```
import numpy as np
dt = 5.0
dx = 10.0
t = 0.02
s = 0.002
nx = 11
nlx = nx - 1
ho = 16.0

hold = np.zeros(nx+1)
hnew = np.zeros(nx+1)

for i in range(nx):
    hold[i] = ho
    hnew[i] = ho

hold[nx] = 11.0
```

However, I can't get over this because I don't know the Python correspondent of the `printf` function. What would be the correct form of this function in Python? What does it reffer to?

Comment: "What does it refer to?" -- what does this mean?

Comment: Have you tried  `print` ?

Comment: https://pyformat.info/

Comment: What is the function of `printf` in the code?

Comment: It prints formatted output. The equivalent in python is print()

Comment: It prints out the data for a given iteration. Set kprint to the iteration number you want to display.

Comment: as an aside, using numpy for this doesn't make any sense, at least not in the way you are using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `print()` in Python with `.format`.

For example:

```py
x, y = 1, 2

print("x = {0}, y = {1}".format(x, y))
```

[Here's the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

To print similar to C's printf, the following is an example:

```
f = 3.25645
g = 3.14159265358979

for fl in (f,g):
    print(f'{fl:.2f}')


3.26
3.14
```

The first `f` in the `print` is the `format` specifier. The `f` in the braces says to consider the number as a float.

Comment: The last sentence is incorrect. Format strings do **absolutely not** support "consider number as a float" - they're formatting instructions *for* a float.

Answer (score 0):

it just `print()` (see a small program below)

```
squares = []
for x in range(14):
 squares.append(x**2)

squares

squares2 = [x**2 for x in range(100)]

print (squares2)
```